# Is there a way to show the permissions for a file without using `ls`

Tags: linux, permissions, ls, aix, chmod

That's all - just wondering if there's other way to find out the permissions for a file without doing a `ls -l` to see the string of values there.

As far as I know, there's no *show* option in `chmod`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides `stat` (Linux-specific), there are tools which allow you to do this as a side effect.  The `tar` program, for example can do this:

```
tar cf - filename | tar tvf -
```

For example

```
$ tar cf - foo |tar tvf -
rwxr-xr-x 1021/1021     18 Jan 13 21:40 2016 foo
```

Using the special `"-"` like that is reasonably portable (it works with [AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/tar.htm), [HPUX](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/unix/usail/man/hpux/tar.1.html), [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/tar-1.html), [Linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html) and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar%281%29)).

The term "reasonably portable" applies to

- availability
- identical format

There are a few comments about stat versus portability.  Here is output from [GNU coreutils `stat`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stat-invocation):

```
$ stat foo
  File: `foo'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 784564      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/     tom)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2016-05-12 19:03:54.773503477 -0400
Modify: 2016-05-12 19:03:54.773503477 -0400
Change: 2016-05-12 19:03:54.773503477 -0400
 Birth: -
```

and output from [BSD stat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1) (OSX):

```
$ stat foo
16777221 61893362 -rwxr-xr-x 1 tom wheel 0 0 "May 12 19:03:54 2016" "May 12 19:03:54 2016" "May 12 19:04:59 2016" "May 12 19:03:54 2016" 4096 0 0 foo
```

And here is an example output from [AIX istat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) (looks *different* to me):

```
$ istat foo
Inode 3166649 on device 32768/13        File
Protection: rwxr-xr-x   
Owner: 1021(dickey)             Group: 1021(dickey)
Link count:   1         Length 18 bytes

Last updated:   Wed Jan 13 21:40:30 UTC 2016
Last modified:  Wed Jan 13 21:40:30 UTC 2016
Last accessed:  Wed Jan 13 21:40:20 UTC 2016
```

Comment: That's actually kind of a clever way of being portable. [Example output](https://dpaste.de/VHwY)

Comment: @Bratchley, isn't `ls -l` even *more* portable, though?

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is generally bad form. In this case it would be just as portable/reliable but it's not what the OP asked. There also isn't a level of portability beyond "all applicable platforms."

Comment: Out of interest, why is `stat` Linux specific? It works on my OS X, FreeBSD, and OpenIndiana machines here…

Comment: AIX has `istat` I believe ([man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm)).

Comment: That's completely (self-censored) - you have to allow IBM to run unknown javascript code on your machine just to view a man page!  I wouldn't do that even if I ran AIX and really needed to view that man page right now and couldn't ssh in to somewhere I could just run `man istat`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more Linux specific and obscure (will need ACL tools installed) but the `getfacl` command will show output similar to this even if there are no ACLs set on a file:

```
[root@mymachine ~#] getfacl my_file.txt
#file: my_file.txt
#owner: root
#group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume AIX has a `perl` of some sort.

```
perl -e 'printf "%03o\n", (stat( $ARGV[0] ))[2] & 07777' /etc/hosts
```

The [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function returns all sorts of exciting metadata about the chosen file. Here, I'm just using the third element (`[2]` counting from zero), which is mostly permissions. The `printf "%03o\n"` outputs the value of the permissions in octal (eg `644`, `1644`, or `007`) with either three or four characters in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat`, as in `stat <filename>`.

Comment: Not sure what the AIX equivalent is, but it doesn't seem to be installed on the AIX 6 box I checked: https://dpaste.de/h6qN

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed the linux tag.